# Simply and friedly tutorial about grub2 command

Tags: command-line, grub2

looking straight constructed an example that describes how many commands for grub2. Perhaps there is an index for grub2 command along with a description and example?
I have been really sick of people who think they know something about it. Help, but also patience.

Comment: This is probably what you need: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Command_002dline-and-menu-entry-commands.html

Comment: This " I have been really sick of people who think they know something about it." makes me not wanting to answer.

Comment: You might have more luck if you ask simple *and* friendly questions :)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Grub commands that do what? Examples of what?

Comment: Read FullCircle Magazine  in issue 15  the Grub 2 tutorial start.
http://fullcirclemagazine.org/downloads/    And do moderate your language!